# Orderby in IQueryable Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm having trouble with following EF lambda expressions.

```
partial void StatusCallBackRequired_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail> query)
{
    var newList = PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetails.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
    query = query.Where(p => p.PatientsMasterItem.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Status == "7") != null);
 }
```

The error is:

> 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.IOrderedDataServiceQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.IOrderedDataServiceQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have already included system.linq namespace.

**EDIT:(the results based on D Stanley code)**

The sample data can be found below and I'm looking to retrieve the highlighted record
[image]

However the current output is

[image]

Changing query to query.select returns only one record but it's is the wrong record.

Comment: Did you rebuild it to make sure you aren't looking at stale compiler errors?

Comment: Are you sure System.Linq has an extension method for IOrderedDataServiceQueryable? When I google IOrderedDataServiceQueryable, then *only* link that comes up is this SO question. I can't even research that type to see if Linq provides an extension method for it.

Comment: Just out of interest why are you delcaring newList then not using it?

Comment: What is `Microsoft.LightSwitch.IOrderedDataServiceQueryable`? Does it extent `IEnumerable`? Or, does it have any extends method `ToList`? If does, you must `using` the namespace that contains the extends method.

Comment: I think the preprocessquery function only supports Iqueryable. Is there an alternative to implement same using IQueryable instead of IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

cast to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var newList = ((IEnumerable<PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>)PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetails.OrderBy(x => x.Id)).ToList();
```

Initialize the list from the query result:

```
var newList = new List<PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>(PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetails.OrderBy(x => x.Id)));
```

**EDIT**
Looks like LightSwitch doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.  Two more things to try:

Assuming it implements `IEnumerable`, use `IEnumerable.Cast<T>()`:

```
var newList = new List<PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>(
    PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetails.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
        .Cast<PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>()
    );
```

brute force:

```
var newList = new List<PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>();
foreach(var item in PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetails.OrderBy(x => x.Id))
    newList.Add(item);
```

Comment: Tried 1st one no compile errors but app crashes when executing this query with following error `Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.QueryImplementation`1[LightSwitchApplication.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LightSwitchApplication.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail]'.`

Comment: 2nd one gives me following errors 
`Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<LightSwitchApplication.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LightSwitchApplication.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>)' has some invalid arguments 
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.IOrderedDataServiceQueryable<LightSwitchApplication.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LightSwitchApplication.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail>' 
`

Comment: I think the preprocessquery function only supports Iqueryable. I still don't understand the differences between EF,ADO.NET, LINQtoSQL etc

Comment: IQueryable derives from IEnumerable, but apparently LightSwitch does not also implement IEnumerable<T>.  I've edited my answer to give you another couple of options.

Comment: IEnumerable.Cast<T>() seems to work. However, the result is not as I expected. May be is it because of not using the list variable ?  How can I apply the ordered new list into the query ?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing more about your data and what you are expecting.  How do you define the "right" record?  Most recent?  Then sort by date descending and take the `FirstOrDefault()`, for example.

Comment: I'm trying to find whether the most record in the table has status = 7. I'm ordering them by ID instead of date. The reason why I have to sort them because unfortunately lightswitch doesn't support lastordefault so I have to swap the order to find the most recent record. Please also refer to the screenshot above in original question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the definition of this type: `Microsoft.LightSwitch.IOrderedDataServiceQueryable`

Once you've found it, confirm:

Does it implement `IEnumerable<T>`?  If so, your code can't reach [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).  You say you are using System.Linq, so make sure your project is referencing `System.Core.dll` .

If not, does it implement `IEnumerable`?  If so, you can write a `foreach` loop and add each item to a `List<T>` that you make.

If not, examine the properties.  There is usually some way to get at the something you can write a loop against.

Comment: I'm using LightSwitch and please refer to this post on [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/3bdedf6d-164b-462d-895b-dc51793d39b7/#4c137c53-094f-423e-96c3-e9aab527d349) for more information.